# What is parent hierarchy of MixingSampleProvider NAudio

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I am using code below for mixing wave files

```
 void Mixingfunction(List<string> inputFiles)
    {
        MixingSampleProvider mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100, 1));
        try
        {

            for (int y = 0; y < counter; y++)
            {
                audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(inputFiles[y]);
                mixer.AddMixerInput((ISampleProvider)audioFileReader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            return;

        }

        if (flag == true)
        {
            mixer.AddMixerInput((ISampleProvider)sineWaveProvider);
        }
        SampleToWaveProvider mixer2 = new SampleToWaveProvider(mixer);
        waveout.Init(mixer2);
        waveout.Play();
    }
```

It points out error   'The type or namespace MixingSampleProvider could not be found'. I have already added reference of Naudio and used

```
 using NAudio;
 using NAudio.Wave;
 using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders;
```

Same problem with `WaveIn` resolved by using `NAudio.Wave.WaveIn`. So what is parent hierarchy of  `MixingSampleProvider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders` So make sure you're using the latest NAudio (1.7.3)

Comment: please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451983/reduce-delay-in-mapping-speaker-and-mic-volume-using-naudio-c-sharp i am struggling with this from long time with naudio.